# Test of an unobtainable value in JSSpec

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I am learning JSSpec. Here's my problem.

In this code :

```
describe("Buttons' events", {

'when I click on a button with an id of #b1...': function() {
    click_me(document.getElementById("b1"));
},

'...then URL should have a parameter b with the value someURL1 and a parameter ui with the value 527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785), because #b1\'s class is .testme': function() {
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/http:\/\/swkyb\.com:9000/);
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/ui=527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785/);
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/b=someURL1/);
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/s=tester/);
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/e=button/);
    value_of(observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/api=testv/);
}
```

I don't understand where the value `527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785` in `observer.URLforTests_lg).should_match(/ui=527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785/);` comes from.
I have looked for this String on my project but I don't find where it is defined (if so).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: `527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785` is just the md5 code for `john`, which is in the project configuration files.